# How to test class method which use class method

Tags: python, django, pytest

I want to mock only part of class methods and assert result with call_args_list but I'm struggling with mock in this case.

I tried many different approaches but still I'havent figured how I can write this unittest.od. I'm aware that my current solution at this moment this test doesn't check anything except PASSED status.

```py
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import call

from django.db import models, transaction


class MyModel(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls, arg1, arg2):
        with transaction.atomic():
            my_model, _ = cls.objects.get_or_create(arg1=arg1,
                                                    defaults={'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2})
            my_model.save()


def test_my_method():
    MyModel = mock.MagicMock()
    MyModel.objects.return_value.get_or_create.return_value = MyModel(arg1='arg1', arg2='arg2')
    MyModel.my_method('arg1', 'arg2')
    assert MyModel.call_args_list == [call(arg1='arg1', arg2='arg2')]
```

I'll be very glad if someone could tell how I can test this function it correctly.

Comment: Why do you need to mock it? Why not just call it and test that the item was created?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to use only unittest without Django test db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

I had to mock **init** method of class.

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import call

from django.db import models, transaction

class MyModel(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def my_method(cls, arg1, arg2):
        with transaction.atomic():
            my_model, _ = cls.objects.get_or_create(arg1=arg1,
                                                    defaults={'arg1': arg1, 'arg2': arg2})
            my_model.save()


def test_my_method():
    MyModel.__init__ = mock.MagicMock()
    MyModel.objects.return_value.get_or_create.return_value = MyModel(arg1='arg1', arg2='arg2')
    MyModel.my_method('arg1', 'arg2')
    assert MyModel.__init__.call_args_list == [call(arg1='arg1', arg2='arg2')]
```